# Users not receiving community "send welcome email" when added to a community

Tags: community

Users not receiving community "send welcome email" when added to a community

I tried what I could do to solve this myself.

I created multiple community users by going into contacts and clicking on manage external users. It tells me that it will send email but they do not receive it.

I tried emails with different domains and I tested with SF Deliver-ability feature and it works there.

I made sure that "Welcome New Member" is clicked in the community admin email section.

Can anyone think of why users are not getting that email?

Comment: Did you check the community user profile is added n community.

Comment: Customer Community User profile is there

Comment: And community is active. If you are in sandbox then also check the system email deliverability

Comment: Do you have DKIM or Email relay activated?

Comment: How would I know? Where to look?

Answer (score 2):

I know this is old and might be pretty basic, but if the above steps did not work, check that the profile the user has is associated with the community.

From Setup | Feature Settings | Communities | All communities.

Select Workspaces next to the Community where you want to add the user as a Community Member

Select Administration | Members | Select the user's Profile | Click on Add.
Click Save.

Ref: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000316118&type=1&mode=1. ==> I know it's a reset password help link, but the idea is the same for receiving all emails, the Profile needs to be available in the community or else no emails will be triggered.

Answer (score 1):

There are following checklists:

1. In community administration --> Email, Checkbox "Send welcome email" must be true.
   [image]
2. Email deliverability should be turned on to "All Email".
3. User's email should be correct and valid email address. Usually, User's email is not valid in sandbox after refresh.
4. Community is activated.

Comment: Yes, all of these things were done.

Comment: Sounds like there is a setting in your email server that is preventing the mail.You might also try running the "Test Deliverability" check in the Email administration. Maybe your email server will not accept inbound email from the developer org.  and ALSO COMMUNITY IS ACTIVATED...

Comment: Sorry, I gave the wrong impression, I am doing this in prodcuction

Comment: Here is one such use-case: user with email domain same as sender email setup in community, receiving the email for "forgot password" link is clicked and followed by providing the username. But the same user is not receiving email if the email-domain is updated to GMAIL, OR any other domain.  @Ayub - which server are you referring to?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old post but I recently had this issue. This will likely apply more to scratch orgs as the licensing is more restrictive but **don't forget to check the community licenses allotted for the org you're in**, especially if this functionality was working then mysteriously stopped.

Navigate to:
Setup >> Company Information and under User Licenses you'll see if you have the licenses to create new users.
[image: License allowance for community shows 0]

It's frustrating as it will create the associated contact, but will silently fail when creating the Community User, therefore no email will be sent.

Answer (score 0):

This may be late to this Question but people might find it helpful.

We have done all the above answers but still we did not receive the welcome email for new user. Then I have activated this 'Let guest users see other members of this site' permission under Administration -> Preferences and then the users started receiving welcome email
[image]